# Clicking from one site to a logged in site. Does it reveal your original site identity?

Tags: web, social-media

Let's say you have an account on a social media site (e.g. Twitter). You set up a fake identity on that site (used a separate email address to sign up, not using your real name etc).

Now let's say you are logged into another site (e.g. news-site.com) as your true identity and that site posts on the social media site. You click the news-site.com link on Twitter and it leads you to the article on the news-site.com site.

By virtue of click metrics (or whatever) can news-site.com connect these two pieces of information and determine your username on the original site (Twitter in this example)? I'm imagining that news-site.com receives info from Twitter about who clicks their post links, and they could connect that info to page requests from their own servers (via time of request or something else.)

news-site.com has your real name/credit card info registered with them so they would know your (anonymous) handle on Twitter also.

Is this possible and is it happening?

Comment: I changed your use of "anonymous" to something more accurate. What you are doing is changing identities. That's the important part.